# Picking an n-digit combination lock with C++

Tags: c++, cryptography, iteration, combinations, combinatorics

I need to write a C++ code to somehow iterate over each combination of a "combination lock" with different possible maximum number of states given for each digit. It is important that there is a specific call to a function for each try. Also, the number of digits may vary runtime.
Can you please help?

This is how I pictured it:

```
bool tryCombination(vector<int> numberToTry)
{
    //...
}

vector<int> pickLock(vector<int> lockToPick)
{
    vector<int> combination(lockToPick.size());

    while( /* ? */ )
    {
        // my question is, what to do here?

        //iterate over all possible combinations of an n digit combination lock, where digits are not necessarily 1-10
        // 0 0 0
        // 1 0 0
        // 2 0 0 ...

        if(tryCombination(combination) == true)
            break;
    }

    return combination;
}

int main()
{
    // Maximum number of states for each digit
    // This is an example, but the length of the vector could vary on each pickLock() call
    vector<int> fourDigitLock_1 = {3, 5, 8, 2};

    vector<int> result = pickLock(fourDigitLock_1);

}
```

Comment: Huh. I happen to have a tool made for scenarios just like this! https://ideone.com/nI0Z7h `while(next_combination(combination.begin(), combination.end(), 0, 10))`

Comment: Where do you get the "*different possible maximum number of states given for each digit*" from? Shouldn't this information be passed into `pickLock` somehow?

Comment: This is just an iteration task with a different base for each "digit". So 1..3 X 1..5 X 1..8 X 1..2. Can you see the pattern if you try it with pen and paper?

Comment: It is straightforward to do this with nested loops, but the way I see it, nesting depth will depend on how many digits I have. And I got puzzled about how to solve this problem in an efficient way. Mooing Duck linked a code here, and it helped me a lot, I will post the modified code here soon. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mooing Duck commented a link (http://www.ideone.com/nI0Z7h) which helped a lot. I just modified it a little, to make it capable of handling different maximal states on each "digit", also to always start from zero (assuming, that the function will always be used only for numeric input). Thanks for your help!
This is the code:

```
template<typename T>
bool next_combination(T* data_begin, T* data_end, T* _max, short* pos)
{
    if (data_begin == data_end) return false; //return is called wrong

    T* data_cur = data_begin;
    while (++*data_cur == _max[*pos]) //when a certain digit has reached its end, this loop takes action. Note the ++*data_cur operation
    {
        *data_cur = 0; //begin from 0 when one digit has rolled around
        ++data_cur;
        ++*pos;
        if (data_cur == data_end )
            return false; //this will terminate the loop what calls this method
    }

    *pos = 0; //step back to beginning
    return true;
}



int main()
{
    //this stores the maximum allowed states for each "digit" on the combination lock
    short dataMax[] = {3, 4, 2};
    short n = 3; //how many "digits" the lock has


    // we will work with these runtime
    short data[n] = {0}; //all values initialized as zeros
    short pos = 0;

    std::cout << "List of all combinations:" << std::endl;
    do {
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) std::cout << data[i]; //instead of this, there could be a call like: tryCombination(data[0], data[1], data[2])
        std::cout << '\n';
    } while(next_combination<short>(&data[0], &data[n], dataMax, &pos));
    return 0;
}
```